# tmux bash exit bash when terminating tmux by default but with exceptions

Tags: bash, tmux

this one is rather complicated to explain and I failed in imagining a short description of this to be able to search for.

My current setting is that when I open a terminal, due to this line

```bsh
if [[ -n "$PS1" ]] && [[ -z "$TMUX" ]]
then
        tmux && exit
fi
```

tmux is started instantly. And since I've got an `&& exit` after the `tmux` command the the tmux encapsulating shell is closed instantly when exiting tmux.

I think this is a nice behaviour by default, but in rare occasions I want to detach or exit tmux without exiting the encapsulating shell.

I thought I'd can do this by entering `exit 1` inside tmux so that the exit code of tmux is `!=0` and thus the `exit` of the encapsulating shell isn't executed, but it seems that tmux is exiting with exit code 0 despite the `exit 1` inside.

Can anyone imagine a way to realize my aim to exit the encapsulating bash by default but being able to manually change this?

Comment: `tmux ; [ -e ~/DoNotExit ] || exit` and then create the file if you don't want to exit? Expand the idea to imclude a PID if you have multiple parallel sessions, maybe throw in an automatic rm of the file?

Comment: Thanks for replying. This is a nice workaround, but regarding the answer I got I think it's better and more convenient to make this without a file to communicate whether the encapsulating shell should terminate or not. But thanks anyway ;)

Comment: I agree the answer you got is better and I upvoted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make tmux detach with a nonzero exit status by doing:

```
tmux detach -E false
```

Perhaps make an alias to do that.

If you want your shell to exit as well, you can do:

```
tmux detach -E false; exit
```

Comment: Oh thanks that's a nice solution (I think I'll bind the normal detatch to `prefix+d` and the detatch but don't kill the encapsulating shell to `prefix + shift +d`)